# Checking if a list starts / ends with any one of many strings in a second list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, what's the best way to check if a list of strings in a column start or end with another list of strings?

Example:

First List:
Reddy
CodeRed
Zabby
KaBlueY

Second List: Red, Blue, Blop, Blurp

The solution should return:
Reddy - TRUE (because it contains 'red' from the second list in the start or end position)
CodeRed - TRUE (because it contains 'red' from the second list in the start or end position)
 
Zabby - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the start or end position.
 
KaBlueY - FALSE (because it does not contain any strings from the second list in the start or end position.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edited Answer:**

The question has been changed, and so should my answer to make it current:

If the second argument of `SEARCH` function is a range, you may use this formula.

**Solution #4: Check if any of the strings in a range contain a substring**

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red",range)))*1
Result: 1

=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("redX",range)))*1
Result: 0
```

Same explanation as Solution #1 below but instead of searching for a substring in a "parent" string, it searches multiple strings and is made possible by creating an array formula and can only be done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Check for `{}` around your formula in the formula bar to make sure that you created an array formula.

Since there are multiple results in an array formula, wrap it with `OR` function to see if any of the strings in a range contain the string that you're looking for. Finally, simply multiply it by 1 to convert the resulting boolean values to its numerical values.

Hope it helps!

---

---

> **Original Answer:**

There are number of ways to do this. You may use `SEARCH` or `SUBSTITUTE` function, to parse the string, in combination with other functions such as those that returns boolean values, to check the expected result against the return value of the former. Finally, to convert boolean values into its numerical values, simply multiply it by 1.

Here are some examples to get you started:

**Solution #1**

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("red","reddy"))*1
Result: 1

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("redX","reddy"))*1
Result: 0
```

If it is able to find the substring `red` within the "parent" string `reddy`, the `SEARCH` function returns a number—the position of the substring you're looking for. Otherwise, like in the case of `redX`, it returns `#VALUE!`. To hide the ugly `#VALUE!` error message as well as to show a more appropriate message than simply showing the position of the substring, wrap it with `ISNUMBER` function to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. And if you'd like to convert it to its numerical values, multiply it by 1.

---

**Solution #2**

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE("reddy","red","anyText")="reddy",FALSE,TRUE)*1
Result: 1

=IF(SUBSTITUTE("reddy","redX","anyText")="reddy",FALSE,TRUE)*1
Result: 0
```

Here, the resulting string from the `SUBSTITUTE` function is compared against the "parent" string by wrapping it with `IF` function, which in turn returns a boolean value that can be converted into a numerical value by multiplying it by 1.

---

**Solution #3**

```
=NOT(EXACT("reddy",SUBSTITUTE("reddy","red","anyText")))*1
Result: 1

=NOT(EXACT("reddy",SUBSTITUTE("reddy","redX","anyText")))*1
Result: 0
```

This is just a variation of the formula presented in Solution #2. It uses `EXACT` function to check if the resulting string from the `SUBSTITUTE` function is exactly the same as the old string (which I called the "parent string" in Solution #1). If it is exactly the same, it means nothing were substituted because it didn't find the string you're looking for. Since `EXACT` function returns `TRUE` if the two strings are an exact match, which means nothing has changed, which also means, it didn't find the string you're looking for, you need to reverse the result by wrapping it with `NOT` function. Again, if you'd like to convert it to its numerical form, simply multiply it by 1.

Hope it helps!

---

**References:**

[SEARCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495)

[ISNUMBER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665)

[OR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0)

[SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

[IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

[EXACT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/exact-function-d3087698-fc15-4a15-9631-12575cf29926)

[NOT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/not-function-9cfc6011-a054-40c7-a140-cd4ba2d87d77)

Comment: the thing is, each list is 1,000+ cells long. Your solutions check if one string matches a second list. I need to check if any of the strings from the second list match the first list. For example in "reddy", does it contain any one of 1,000+ strings. Then for the next cell down, say, "bluey", does that contain any one of 1,000+ strings. etc.

Comment: The thing is, your question is poorly constructed. Look at your edit history, it has 7 revisions. Your original post read as one-line question followed by a code `=IF("reddy"=("red"&"*"),1, 0)` and then a question/statement like a confused person. What am I, a mind reader? I really suggest that you read [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).